# Concrete type error in code from Swift 3.0.1 while adding constraints to protocol extensions

Tags: swift, swift3

From The Swift Programming Language Guide:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element:TextRepresentable
{
   var textualDescription:String {
      let itemsAsText = self.map { $0.textualDescription }
      return "[" + itemsAsText.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
   }
}
```

...

```
let hamsters = [murrayTheHamster, morganTheHamster, mauriceTheHamster]

print(hamsters.textualDescription)
```

At this point the compiler tells me:

> Using 'TextRepresentable' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'TextRepresentable' is not supported.

I was a bit surprised, since the code is right out of the language guide.  Is this an error in the language guide, or have I typed something incorrectly?  Or perhaps my compiler settings are wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the guide again – `murrayTheHamster`, `morganTheHamster` and `mauriceTheHamster` are typed as `Hamster`, not `TextRepresentable`. Protocols don't conform to themselves, so you cannot use `TextRepresentable` as a type that conforms to `TextRepresentable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me with Xcode Version 8.2 beta (8C23):

```
import UIKit

protocol TextRepresentable {
    var textualDescription: String { get }
}

extension Collection where Iterator.Element:TextRepresentable
{
    var textualDescription:String {
        let itemsAsText = self.map { $0.textualDescription }
        return "[" + itemsAsText.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
    }
}

struct Hamster {
    var name: String
    var textualDescription: String {
        return "A hamster named \(name)"
    }
}
extension Hamster: TextRepresentable {}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let murrayTheHamster = Hamster(name: "Murray")
        let morganTheHamster = Hamster(name: "Morgan")
        let mauriceTheHamster = Hamster(name: "Maurice")
        let hamsters = [murrayTheHamster, morganTheHamster, mauriceTheHamster]

        print(hamsters.textualDescription)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```